# Retrolambda on Google App Engine

Tags: maven, google-app-engine, maven-3, appengine-maven-plugin, retrolambda

Is anyone using Retrolambda for a Google App Engine project? What does your pom.xml look like?

It's straightforward to compile for JDK8 and set up retrolambda's maven plugin. However, to deploy to GAE, Google's appengine-maven-plugin needs to be run under JDK7 otherwise it will compile JSP files into a format that breaks in production.

How can I use JDK8+retrolambda for compilation, but JDK7 for appengine:update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometime after I posted this question, Google made a change to the SDK (or the maven plugin) and fixed compatibility with JDK8.

Consequently, retrolambda now works as advertised. It's a huge productivity boost when working on GAE. Just make sure to run the test harness with JDK7 in your CI system.